# Skein theory: How axiomatizing a 2-box space?

Tags: subfactors, planar-algebras

Let $(A,+,\times, *)$ with an adjoint operation compatible with $+$, $\times$ and $*$, such that $(A,+,\times)$ and $(A,+,*)$ are finite dimensional ${\rm C}^{*}$-algebras.

What are the axioms on $A$ so that $(A,+,\times) \simeq P_{2,+}$, $(A,+,*) \simeq P_{2,-}$, with $P$ a subfactor planar algebra?

*Remark*: I expect axioms more simple than those of a subfactor planar algebra $P$ together with the assumption that $P$ is generated by its $2$-box space.